# Get a header from HTTP response

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I can't figure out how to get the Content-Length header from the response from a server:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

main = do 
      headers <- getHeaders "http://fdsfdsfds.fd"

      --??? this doesn't compile and a wrong way to go
      head $ filter (\x -> hContentLength (fst x)) headers

getHeaders :: String -> IO ResponseHeaders
getHeaders url = do
  req <- parseUrl url
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs req
  return $ responseHeaders res
```

Your suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure, a Content-Length header is sent?

Comment: @Seb, it's not about whether it is sent or not. It's about a solution how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `hContentLength` is just a case-insensitive string, not a function. You can't apply it.

However, since `CI a` is an instance of `Eq` for any `Eq a`, you can simply use `lookup`:

```
getContentLength :: ResponseHeaders -> Maybe ByteString
getContentLength = lookup hContentLength
```

Comment: `hContentType is just a case-insensitive string` what does that mean? in the documentation I can't see its being a string.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: [`hContentLength`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.8.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html#v:hContentLength) is a `HeaderName`, which is a `CI ByteString`.

Comment: by the way, there isn't "Content-Disposition" header, is there? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.8.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-Header.html#t:HeaderName

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: No, but you could implement it easily, just follow the implementation of the other fields. However, you could need one or another extension (at least`OverloadedStrings`).